# How to get File Uri from file path? (Scoped Storage)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, scoped-storage

I want to edit a text file stored at a certain path I know of. I just want MediaStore Uri for that file path so that I can create a write request with MediaStore.createWriteRequest(). How can I do that?

Comment: What does this have to do scoped storage?

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me

```
Uri.fromFile(File(filepath))
```

Comment: I have tried this it throws IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be referenced by specific ID, it's happening cuz the Uri is not a MediaStore Uri afaik.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check permission on devices greater than API 28 and other devices.

```
public static boolean checkPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 28 || hasAll(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        return true;
    } else if(hasAll(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE){
        return true;
    }
}
    
public static boolean hasAll(@NonNull Context context, String... permissions) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
    Stream.of(permissions).allMatch(permission -> ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```